# How does Python know whether a variable in the class is a method or a variable?

Tags: python

```
print(hasattr(int,         '__call__'))
print(hasattr(lambda x: x, '__call__'))
print('')

class A(object):
    a = int
    b = lambda x : x

print(A.a)
print(A.b)
```

results in

```
True
True

<type 'int'>
<unbound method A.<lambda>>
```

How does Python decide what is going to be a method (as `A.b` is here) and what is just going to be itself (as `A.a` is here)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things are wrapped into methods if they are functions (that is, their type is `types.FunctionType`).

This is because the function type defines a `__get__` method, implementing the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), which changes what happens when `A.b` is looked up.  `int` and most other non-function callables do not define this method:

```
>>> (lambda x: x).__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of function object at 0x0000000003710198>
>>> int.__get__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
    int.__get__
AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute '__get__'
```

You could make your own method-wrapper-like behavior by defining some other sort of descriptor.  An example of this is the `property`.  `property` is a type that is not a function, but also defines a `__get__` (and `__set__`) to change what happens when a property is looked up.